# Flipping a fair coin three times: How to find independent/dependent events?

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

Given that I have a fair coin which I toss three times, how do I:

a) Find three events $A$ , $B$, and $C$ such that no two are independent but $P( A  \cap B \cap C) = P( A ) P( B) P( C)$ ?

b) Find three events $A$ , $B$, and $C$ such that every two are independent but all three are not independent: $P( A  \cap B \cap C) \not= P( A ) P( B) P( C)$ ?

How would I approach a problem like this ? I started by drawing a binary tree that ended up with 8 leaves but I have no idea how to use it to get the answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that homework?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.